# Checking which IPs that had access to Azure VM

Tags: azure

How can I check which IPs accessed my Azure VM also which IPs carried out a data transfer out

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What exactly you want to see? You can check some IN/OUT request from matrix section.